# Что такое Raycast в Unity и как он работает?

Tags: unity3d

поясните на примере что это такое и как оно работает

Answer (score 9):

`Raycast` это некоторый луч, испускаемый из некоторого объекта в некотором направлении некоторой длины (либо бесконечный) для определения коллизий (столкновений) с объектами. После испускания луча мы получаем объект (либо массив объектов если используем `Physics.RaycastAll`), с которыми он столкнулся и далее можем определить попали ли в нужный нам объект. Часто используется в стрельбе. Пример кода с пояснениями (взято с [Unity3D.ru](http://www.unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=35936)):

```
void Update(){
    //сюда запишется инфо о пересечении луча, если оно будет
    RaycastHit hit;
    //сам луч, начинается от позиции этого объекта и направлен в сторону цели
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, target.position - transform.position);
    //пускаем луч
    Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);

    //если луч с чем-то пересёкся, то..
    if (hit.collider != null){
        //если луч не попал в цель
        if (hit.collider.gameObject != target.gameObject){
            Debug.Log("Путь к врагу преграждает объект: "+hit.collider.name);
        }   
        //если луч попал в цель
        else{
            Debug.Log("Попадаю во врага!!!");
        }
        //просто для наглядности рисуем луч в окне Scene
        Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point,Color.red);
    }
}
```

Comment: что такое `target` ?

Comment: @Kill Noise, это объект, в сторону которого испускается луч (например цель для стрельбы)