# Расскажите все о RayCast2D в Unity и как работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Думаю все, кто начинает разрабатывать на Unity, так или иначе приходят к RayCast`ам. На русском инфы про то, как работают лучи в 2D почти ничего нет.

Расскажите пожалуйста, как они устроены, что за что отвечает и как настраивать.

P.S Я знаю, что это скорее просьба, а не вопрос, и что он не ясно построен, но буду рад информации

Comment: думаю что пора учить английский (или же учится пользоваться переводчиком) и ознакомится с той информацией, которая дана в официальной документации к юнити. Ее более чем достаточно для того, что бы пользоваться юнити.

Answer (score 0):

Уже был похожий вопрос, посмотри [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845129/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-raycast-%D0%B2-unity-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82)!

Хорошее видео есть [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZrJjlgNgjE) у Graphical Design, на примере стрельбы в 2д игре показывает как использовать raycast

А вообще, лучше всего будет прошерстить самому иностранные источники посмотри [расширения](https://netpeak.net/ru/blog/luchshiye-rasshireniya-perevodchiki-v-google-chrome-story/) для мгновенного перевода страницы, скачай и в путь, покорять англоязычные сайты :)

ту же самую [официальную страницу](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) по Physics2D.Raycast